# UrlRewrite not for any resource files

Tags: java, regex, jakarta-ee, url-rewriting

I am using Tuckeys UrlRewrite for redirecting any requests made on my application so that I can do some actions depending on the url. I need to be able to catch any requests, but I don't want to get the one from the resources, so basically it would be anything that looks like `/images/something.png` or `/css/something.css`, but I need to be able to catch `/web/http://www.google.com/` for example. Basically, there are only a few number of possibilities for the resources, I just can't figure out how to exclude them. At first, I was able not to take them by not having the `\.` in the regex, but then the example with google wouldn't work. So I need to catch the dots as well, and also since I am not that good with regex I couldn't figure out how to catch ampersand as well.

So I have two questions:

1. How do I catch anything except for resources that could start with `/images/` for example (if it's a `<condition>` element then others would be easy)
2. How to catch urls with ampersands too (actually could be in the first question too)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RewriteCond` ([doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)) to do it.

Comment: hum could you give an example? because reading the doc, it says `The goal of this rule is to force the use of a particular hostname, in preference to other hostnames which may be used to reach the same site. For example, if you wish to force the use of www.example.com instead of example.com, you might use a variant of the following recipe.` I don't see how I could use this